# Azure Equivalent of Resource Group Local Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-group

I've had a little dig through azure documentation but couldn't find a definitive answer.

I have an app service and an azure db sitting in the same resource group, and I am finding the site takes a long time to connect and get responses back from the database only in the hosted environment.

Is it possible to specify a localhost equivalent as they are in the same resource group, and would this make things any quicker?

Answer (score 0):

Resource Group does not have any impact on the connectivity or latency of the application and the database. It is just to group the Azure resources together based on a Project/Envrionment.

There is no equivalent for resourcegroup or even appservice unless if you want to run your application in IIS or any other server.

If you really want to see what is causing the connectivity issue, i will recommend you to monitor the request and response using Azure Monitor.

I think you need to understand the cloud concepts first before trying out anything.